# Appending HTML-Data from another file to a div

Tags: jquery, html, file, append

I want to append HTML-Blocks into my website from an external file. The file is on my server and contains a blueprint for a list entry. When the user searches something, the results should be appended with a loop and displayed with the code from the external HTML file.

Here is the structure of my page:

**The main page**

```
<div id="content">
  // Display List elements here
<div>
```

**My JQuery code**

```
$.('#search-btn').click(function(){
  getElements();
});

function getElements(){
  // Getting elements from server and saving the in the variable data
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    // Append the Elements to the div with id="content"
  }
}
```

**Blueprint for an element, diffrent HTML file**

```
<div class="element">
  <p class="show_name"></p>
  <p class="show_email"></p>
  <p class="show_birthday"></p>
</div>
```

So, I need to append multiple blueprints to the content-div of the main page.
Any ideas on how to implement this using JQuery? :)

Comment: Have you take a look at jQuery.ajax?

Comment: like @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ said using ajax will do the trick and you can append the HTML to the div.

Comment: I would use Angular instead, and use routeProvider to inject content into the div on the page

Comment: And how to I get the adress of my blueprint? If I'm using ajax I need to perform a get request, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this solution

```
function getElements(){
  var div = $('#content');
  // Getting elements from server and saving the in the variable data
  $.get( "/url/to/file.html", function(response) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      div.append($(response));
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: I did that, but nothing happens, I dont' know how to specify the path. Right now I am using "$.get( "../../views/partials/list_element.ejs", function..." but I does not load the file

Comment: HTML-file must be available from web. So you need to configure your web-server to allow access to the file by some path and then you can use that path to load file via jQuery

Comment: Well, the file is on the server, but I don't understand why you need to perform a http get request to get it. The application is running on a Node JS server, so I have to create routes for every element I want to include to my website!?

Comment: Well, in this case you can use a template engine within nodejs and render that partial to main page on server

Comment: Okay, thank you for that, it works kinda. The problem I have now, is that my JQuery and CSS is not affecting the new appended HTML code. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this issue? :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a main div with class name 'main', and you can use this code:

```
function getElements() {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        $(".main").append("<div class='content'><div class='show_name'>"+data.value1+"</div><div class='show_email'>"+data.value2+"</div><div class='show_birthday'>"+data.value3+"</div></div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't it be much cleaner if you export the design into a diffrent HTML file, instead of generating HTML within a JQuery function?

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
function getElements1(){
  var data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  // Getting elements from server and saving the in the variable data
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    // Append the Elements to the div with id="content"
    $('#content').append(data[i]);
  }
}
$('#search-btn').click(function(){
  getElements1();
});
```

See the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/9p77afc3/12/